# Should I write "DNA is" or "DNA are"?

Tags: difference, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

When I'am writing a paper, I did not know what is the difference between *"is"* and *"are"*.

Should I write:

> "DNA **is** a part of....."

instead of:

> "DNA **are** a part of....."

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is" for singular things, "are" for plural items. Deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) is singular. It **is** a thread-like chain of nucleotides carrying the genetic instructions used in the growth, development, functioning and reproduction of all known living organisms and many viruses.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA

This car is red.

Those cars are blue, grey and white.

Answer (score 0):

If ever in doubt, de-abbreviate the term, and then apply conjugation rules.  The abbreviated form is subject to the same rules as the full form.